# windows10 command window not responding to msbuild of a vbproj file

Tags: vb.net, wpf

All these days i was successfully compiling,debugging any v.net wpf project from cmd window;i was using the syntax similar to:-

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin 
msbuild "D:\WPF\GUI_Maker\GUI\GUI_1.vbproj" /t:Build
```

and was able to compile successfully.Suddenly the cmd does not respond to this and also commands like javac,ipconfig,and netsh etc.Environmental path is ok-
C:\WINDOWS\system32;  - is correctly placed in the beginning.
  Can anybody find a solution for this.I have tried exhaustively in the net.

regards and thanks in advance,
kvinvisibleguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your `PATH` is broken.

> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

You need to surround the `PATH=...` with quote `"` characters because it contains parentheses `(`, which need to be escaped as they have a [special meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html).

Use the following command:

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [syntax-brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"

C:\Windows\System32>msbuild.exe "D:\WPF\GUI_Maker\GUI\GUI_1.vbproj" /t:Build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\WPF\GUI_Maker\GUI\GUI_1.vbproj

C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: Not working:-MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\WPF\GUI_Maker\GUI\GUI_1.vbproj

Comment: Thanks David;The following works:-                                                                                                             cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
msbuild.exe D:\WPF\GUI_Maker\GUI\GUI_2.vbproj /t:Build

Comment: I am sure the above problem is created by Microsoft's latest updates                                                                                                            kvinvisibleguy